# $\operatorname{lcm}(a^2, ab, b^2) =\operatorname{lcm}(a^2, b^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two integers. Is it true that $\operatorname{lcm}(a^2, ab, b^2) = \operatorname{lcm}(a^2, b^2)$ ?

$a, b$ are integers and the result that i tried to use, in this case,is $ \operatorname{lcm}(a^2,b^2)\gcd(a^2,b^2)=a^2 b^2$ but i don't know if it's true $\operatorname{lcm}(a^2,ab,b^2)\gcd(a^2,ab,b^2)=a^3 b^3$

I did some examples apparently it's true but I can't prove it. So could give me a hint?

Comment: Please show at least some attempts or partial results you found towards the proof. Also, are $a$ and $b$ integers? polynomials? multivariate polynomials?

Comment: a, b are integers and the result that i tried to use, in this case,is $lcm(a^2,b^2)gcd(a^2,b^2)=a^2*b^2$ but i don't know if it's true $lcm(a^2,ab,b^2)gcd(a^2,ab,b^2)=a^3*b^3$

Comment: $lcm(x,y)=xy/gcd(x,y)$, let $d=gcd(a,b)$, $lcm(a^2,ab)=a(ab)/d$, $lcm(a(ab)/d,b^2)=b\,lcm(a^2/d,b)=$.. It suffices to show that $gcd(a^2/gcd(a,b),b)=gcd(a,b)$ which follows from $gcd(a/d,b)=1$

Comment: Okay, this is better. But keep in mind that $\operatorname{lcm}\left(u,v,w\right)\gcd\left(u,v,w\right)$ is not the same as $uvw$, so you cannot apply the gcd$\cdot$lcm rule to three numbers.

Comment: I don't understand @AlexeyBurdin's comment, but here is my hint: First show that $\operatorname{lcm}\left(a^2,b^2\right) = \left(\operatorname{lcm}\left(a,b\right)\right)^2$. (For this, you can use the gcd$\cdot$lcm rule.) Then, you only need to show that $\left(\operatorname{lcm}\left(a,b\right)\right)^2$ is a multiple of $ab$ is well. This has a very direct proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $\,a^2,b^2\mid m\Rightarrow(ab)^2\!\mid m^2\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{ab}\mid m,\,$ by $\,r\in\Bbb Q,\,r^2\in\Bbb Z\Rightarrow r\in \Bbb Z,\,$ by [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242)
Thus $\,\color{#0a0}{a^2,b^2}\mid m\!\iff a^2,\color{#c00}{ab},b^2\mid m^{\phantom{|^|}}\!$
so  $\,\ {\rm lcm}(\color{#0a0}{a^2,b^2}) = {\rm lcm}(a^2,ab,b^2)^{\phantom{|^|}}\! $ via [LCM Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3231844/242)  (or by: above $(\!\!\iff\!\!)$ shows both sides have same set $S$ of common multiples $m,\,$ so the same *least* common multiple $= \min S$).

**Alternatively** with $[x,y]:={\rm lcm}(x,y)\,$ & applying [LCM distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1163840/242) to expand products

$ [a,b][aa,bb] = [aaa,aab,abb,bbb] = [a,b]^3\,$ so $\,[aa,bb] = [a,b]^2\,$ by cancelling $[a,b]\neq 0,\,$

same as in the [GCD Freshman's Dream](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75974/242) $\,(a^n,b^n) = (a,b)^n = (a^n, a^{n-1}b,\ldots, a b^{n-1}a, b^n)$